# Preprocessor, Postprocessor, Geometric Processor and NC processor

Tags: preprocessor, processor, microprocessors, boost-preprocessor

Hello Guys! Can anyone explain me the difference between these terms: Preprocessor, Postprocessor, Geometric Processor and NC Processor?

Comment: -1... Really strange collection of tags - preprocessor and microprocessors in the same list? And no language specific tag?

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is incomplete, but a 'pre' processor is basically a process that goes through before your main process, and a 'post' processor goes through after the main process.

So if you're main process is designed to do math, you might have a pre-processor that pre-processes the user input, turning

5+5*2

into...

2 5 * 5 +

Which is actually easier to write a LISP function to process.

The result would be a plain old '15', but a post processor might do something on that result.